# Graphic "area" for drawing vector lines on IPad

Tags: ipad

Being an absolutely beginner on programming the Ipad I have gotten to the point where i can place various controls on a view and interact with them.

What I like to do is to have a defined area on to which I can do some vector drawing. (horisontal/vertical lines etc and tiny graphic objects).

The "area" should be rectangular like a component with a border etc with a size and position.

I somewhat assume I need a separate view for this and have seen som examples of a view with a drawRect where functions like CGContextAddlineToPoint are called.

The problem I have is where/when and how to load this view ?

For example I may want to press a button on the screen to ask a webservice for some data which on return should produce som lines on this graphic area.

I have already some some response functions for buttonclick in my viewcontroller.

If somebody could help me to move on I would be grateful.

regards

martin

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need a custom view class for that and override the `drawRect:` method for your drawing.

You can use CoreGraphics (the C functions that have the `CG` prefix, like the `CGContextAddLineToPoint` function). To get the CoreGraphics context, use [UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext).

But I recommend to read about [UIBezierPath](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html) (also search for *UIBezierPath* here on StackOverflow and on Google to find lots of examples). There's also a [guide from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/BezierPaths/BezierPaths.html).

Comment: Hi, Thanks.
I have already a custom view .h and .m file (ripped from an iphone sample) which draws with the CG functions in an overrided drawRect function.

The problem is how to load that from my viewcontroller som that it positions itself between other components in the existing view.

PS i am aware of the richer bezierfunctions, but that'll be next step.

How do I load this extra view ?